# Apply using characters

Tags: r, apply, r-sf

I'm working with `sf` objects and I have a question about applying user-defined functions to data frames.  This is a silly example, but it is similar to what I'm trying to do with a more complicated problem.  I have a data frame called `names` that has two columns, each with the name of a county.  I also read in the North Carolina data included with the `sf` package.

```
require(sf)
name_1 <- c('Ashe','Alleghany','Surry')
name_2 <- c('Currituck','Northampton','Hertford')
names <- data.frame(cbind(name_1,name_2))
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
```

What I'm trying to do is create a function that goes down each row of my data frame `names`, takes the name out of the name_1 column and the name out of the name_2 column, and sees if they intersect using the geometric data in `nc`.  I have:

```
check_intersection <- function(x){
  return(st_intersects(nc[nc$NAME== x$name_1,],nc[nc$NAME==x$name_2,],sparse = FALSE))
}
apply(names,1,check_intersection)
```

But this yields an error of `Error in x$name_1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.  How do I tell the function to get the character values out of the appropriate columns, for each row in `names`?

Comment: Could you not subset your sf object by each vector and then run an st_intersects or st_intersection on the two objects? Not understanding why you need them in the same df

Comment: try: `check_intersection <- function(x){
  return(st_intersects(nc[nc$NAME== x[1],],nc[nc$NAME==x[2],],sparse = FALSE))
}`

Comment: You can't use `$` operator with vectors. Replace x$name_1 and the others with something like x[,1] and x$name_2 with x[,2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
apply(names, 1, 
  function(x) 
    st_intersects(nc[nc$NAME == x[1],], nc[nc$NAME == x[2],], 
       sparse = FALSE)
)
```

In the anonymous function, `x` is a vector, not a `data.frame`, hence `$` does not work.